# C++: Pointers pointing to freed memory space

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

The two lines of code at the bottom `tail = head;
            tail->next= NULL;` causes the program to crash, when I call the `extractMin()` function. If i comment them out, everything is happening as supposed. Is this happening cause they are pointing to addresses in memory that has been freed?

The only clue the compiler gives me is this:`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)`. I notice immediately the address being 0x0 so there is a problem  there, but what exactly?

```
string LinkedListPQueue::extractMin() {
    if (isEmpty())
        error("Tried to dequeue from epmpty queue!");

    cell *toBeDeleted = head;   //pointer to this head
    string value = head->value; //get value of this head
    head = head->next;          //move so this head is not the same as the one to be deleted
    delete toBeDeleted;         //delete previous head.
    return value;

}


/* Implementation notes: enqueue
 * -----------------------------
 * We have to search to find the proper position, which can be a bit tricky with
 * a singly-linked list.  We walk two parallel pointers, one a step behind the other,
 * until we find the correct position to insert the new cell, which we then splice
 * into place. Note the special case of inserting at the head. Alternatively, this
 * operation could work recursively.
 */
void LinkedListPQueue::enqueue(const string& elem) {
    cell *cur, *prev, *newOne = new cell;

    newOne->value = elem;


    for (prev = NULL, cur = head; cur != NULL; prev=cur, cur = cur->next) {
        if (elem > cur->value) break;
    }
    newOne->next = cur;
    if (prev) {
        prev->next = newOne;
        logSize++; 
    } else {
        head = newOne;
        tail = head;
        tail->next= NULL;
        logSize++;
    }
```

Comment: I can't see any errors at first sight. Use a debugger, it will show you the exact line in your code where the illegal access happens.

Comment: What is `tail`? It does not seem to be rational to set tail (possibly the end of the list) when replacing the head.

Comment: I think I am setting tail to point to head. then setting tail to NULL, which again set´s head to NULL. There was someone outlining this, but deleted the post for whatever reasons. Gosh! pointers are confusing to work with at first.

Comment: @TomLilletveit: Pencil and paper (drawing boxes and arrows) are the best tools for debugging pointer problems.

Comment: Can't you just get rid of the `tail`? I don't see how and why you have a tail in a singly-linked list. How I see it, you only need to replace `head` with `newOne` and make sure `newOne->next` points to the old `head`. You're already doing both: when `prev == NULL`, `cur == head` and you're already setting `newOne->next = cur`.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: Tail pointers are used to speed up append operations.  Without a tail pointer, the whole list needs to be traversed to find the appending point.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I agree that it's useful when using a linked list as an *unsorted* list or queue, but not so much for a *sorted* priority queue. (I should probably have clarified that I was talking about a *sorted* list as used by the OP.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `else` clause is broken.  If `prev` was null, then you are trying to insert before the first element.

```
else {
  cell *oldHead = head;
  head = newOne;
  head->next = oldHead;
  logSize++;
}
```

Setting `tail->next = NULL` is the core error.